# How to rest user name from Microsoft API?

Tags: api, oauth

I'm using Microsoft OAuth 2.0. When I go to link :

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?.....,`

it's will verify and return me go back to my website. By the way, I can get `"code"` or `"id_token"` from Microsoft OAuth 2.0.

But I don't know how I can get username (such as abcxyz@company.com) with them???

For like an example, when I used :

`https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?...`

for login, as the same in above, I can get `"access_token"`, then I can get username via :

```
 //apis*live*net/v5.0/me?access_token="The token that I got".
```

But for **login.microsoftonline.com**, i don't know how to get it?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: id_token can contain username in claims. Could you share entire token with claims?
Also it's good idea to share your test request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize

Comment: I am 90% sure you are looking for `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/`

Comment: Thank you, but how to get user via your link?
is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?id_token="id token that i got"?

Answer (score 0):

Because I am an amateur so I don't know that when I have the id_token, it mean I have username information. We can use php decode base 64 for decode the id_token and get any information that we want.

```
echo base64_decode($id_token); //$id_token is the string that we got
```

Thank you :)